# How to use bootstrap-icons as svgs in a vue project build by vue-cli

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, icons, vue-cli

I tried to use bootstrap-icons library in my vue project, right now I just import the CSS file so I can use as a icon font("i" tag).But I want to use them as svgs so I can use linear-gradient for color filling.

I installed bootstrap-icons to my project with

```
npm i bootstrap-icons
```

and use try to use them as it said on the website:

```
<svg class="bi" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor">
  <use xlink:href="bootstrap-icons.svg#heart-fill"/>
</svg>
```

It's not working, and I tried to use require() for the xlink:href or use v-bind to link the value to a var, none of them work, throwing error with "Cannot find module" or "Get 404". I tried to copy the bootstrap-icons document out side the node_modules and put it under the root, change the value of xlink:href to be "bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.svg#heart-fill", still not working.

I'm a noob for vue and I build this project with vue-cli. I cannot figure out what is going on with this problem and I didn't find the solution on the Internet. Did any one meet the same problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### static link

You can use the `~` shortcut to reference assets in `node_modules` (see [here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html#transform-rules)):

```
<svg class="bi" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor">
  <use xlink:href="~/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.svg#heart-fill"/>
</svg>
```

#### dynamic link

If you need dynamic binding you can use the fact that `require` returns a path to the required svg-file:

```
<template>
  <svg class="bi" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor">
    <use :xlink:href="`${iconUrl}`"/>
  </svg>
</template>

<script>
const iconPath = require('bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.svg');

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      iconUrl: iconPath + '#heart-fill'
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

You can do the same with import instead of require:

```
import iconPath from 'bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.svg'
```

If you wonder where this behaviour is defined you can inspect your default vue-cli webpack-config as described [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#inspecting-the-project-s-webpack-config).

### font

Although this is not exactly what you where asking for you could use the CSS icon font instead of svg:

```
<template>
  <i :class="iconClass" style="font-size: 32px;"></i>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      iconClass: 'bi-heart-fill'
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>
  @import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css";
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you, although it works but I still have a problem--I'd like to v-bind the xlink:href value so I can generate svg icon dynamicly. But now what I do is  <use :xlink:href="\`~/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.svg#${fileType}\`"></use>
and it will throw an error that said "GET http://localhost:8080/~/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.svg net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)"
I tried to use require or use a var to repersent the whole string, none of them works for me.

Comment: Added an example for dynamic binding. Please check!